# Rollback to a specific moment with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to rollback to a specific starting point.
Im looking for something like this.

Start specific_point;

Now after this, an other application connected with the SAME login will insert & delete datas (webservices with crud operations)
for about 2 minutes doing tests. Each webservice call is declared as a transaction with Spring Ws.

After that i want to rollback to the specific_point to have a clean database to a known previous state.

I was thinking that 
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT foo; was the solution but not unfortunately?

Any idea ?

Configuration: PostgreSQL 8.4 / windows XP

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Two quick options:

1. Create a temporary database using the primary database as a template, drop the temporary database when finished testing.
2. [Table Log](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/tablelog/) might be helpful in implementing something.

Comment: +1 for a temporary database, but make tests on temporary - not on live database.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if all your applications share the same database connection. They may not create their own connection. You could do this with a connection pool, just allow one connection. If someone can create it's own connection, game over. Different connections can not share the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

SAVEPOINTs only work inside one transaction, which means one connection.

You can build something off PITR, which lets you do a *restore* to a specific point in time. You'll need a base backup to work from, and the archived log files, but that lets you roll forward to a specific point in time. It's not as "convenient" as what you seem to be looking for, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a requirement like that is for testing purposes.

There is the following alternative:

- At the specific point, disconnect all users from the database and clone it:

  ```
  CREATE DATABASE mydb_template
     TEMPLATE mydb
     ALLOW_CONNECTIONS FALSE
     IS_TEMPLATE TRUE;
  ```
- Then let the tests do their work.
- To restore the database, disconnect everybody from it and run

  ```
  CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE mydb_template;
  ```